# shell script for SGE cluster

Tags: arrays, r, shell, cluster-computing, sungridengine

I am a novice bash programmer who is having  some difficulty submitting an array job on a SGE HPC cluster. I am using an R module on the cluster to run a custom analysis routine ("CIfinal.rFunc") that I wrote. The script is functional but I am not familiar with writing shell scripts. Here is my attempt at writing a shell script:

```
#!/bin/bash

#$ -S /bin/bash
#$ -V
#$ -cwd
#$ -j y
#$ -N R-job
#$ -t 1-6

source /apps1/modules/init/sh
module purge
module load R/intel/3.0.1

parameters=(1 2 3 4 5 6)

#n_parameters=${#parameters[@]}
#for((i=1; i<$n_parameters; i++)); do
#    echo ${parameters[i]}
#
#done

#exit

index=$(($SGE_TASK_ID - 1))

arg1=${parameters[$index]}

cd $HOME/rDAT

cat <<EOF | R --no-save -q 
load("CIfinal.rFunc")
CIfinal.rFunc($arg1, 1)
EOF

exit
```

This script returns an error:line 26: parameters: bad array subscript
This refers to the arg1=${parameters[$index]} line

It appears to me that the parameters are not being passed to the function so there must be something off either with the syntax in the loop or with one of the bash commands or both.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: What is the value of `SGE_TASK_ID`?  If it is unset, then you are indexing with -1, and getting the expected error.

Comment: I suggest that you modify your script to display all environment variables with the "env" command.  Then you can verify if SGE_TASK_ID is set, and what other variables are set.